# class.forname fails when getting classname from properties file

Tags: jdbc

when I try to load an Oracle JDBC driver classname from a file (properties file) and then pass it to Class.forName the result is a ClassNotFoundException.
When passing the Argument as a string, all works.

Can anyone explain why this happens?

```
String driverName = (String) props.getProperty"db.driverClassName"); //returns "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";
Class.forName(driverName); --> Fails with a ClassNotFoundException
```

If however I use:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
```

all works fine.

Both times the argument is a String, so what could be the problem?

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: My guess is that the driver name isn't really "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver". Check leading/trailing spaces, special characters. Dump the numeric value of each char.

Comment: Prove it: post the code dumping the two strings as sequence of chars in their numeric form, post the output of the dumps, and post the complete exception stack trace.